# Как обратиться к файлам, находящимся в директории assets моего android приложения?

Tags: android

Как обратиться к файлам, находящимся в директории assets моего android приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно еще проще через URL: `file:///android_asset/myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("myfile.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
```